# Can we hit a URL and check for the response as a job in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

Say I have a URL like (https://hello.world.com). Is it possible to hit this URL in Azure Data Factory and observe the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can use the `Web` activity.
Specify the URL you want and choose `Get` as method.
This will output the html content in the *response* json element.

[image]